# Selo W3C para meus sites

Tags: bootstrap, w3c-validador

Boa noite.

Ao conversar com amigos, me falaram que seria interessante colocar o selo de validação da W3C no site. O fato de ter o selo, além de tornar o site mais leve e sem erros, é bem melhor para SEO (foi o que ouvi).

De qualquer forma, fui visitar o site da validação: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

Quando tentei passar um site meu, apareceram CENTENAS de erros. A maioria, voltada para o Bootstrap.

A minha questão é a seguinte: Esse selo é realmente importante? Se positivo, não devo usar o Bootstrap ou qualquer Framework?

Comment: O selo não, tanto que você não o vê por aí. Inclusive tem algumas coisas que são exigidas pra ele que na prática são ruins. Fazer ser leve, padrão, que esteja em ordem é algo bom. Eu não gosto de *framework* e ser leve e usar *framework*  costuma ser coisas antagônicas.

Comment: @bigown, concordo com você, não dá pra ser leve e usar o bootstrap, eu o uso pela facilidade em vários aspectos, não tive grandes problemas até hoje. Mas, depois desse assunto, estou pensando em repensando em montar tudo do zero, sem depender de nenhum framework. Sempre disse que era pra preguiçoso, e caí na armadilha...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O selo não é importante para o usuário, mas é importante para a comunidade de desenvolvedores que advogam a favor das especificações da W3C, porém não garante coisa alguma.

Alguns site usam os selos da W3 Consortioum apenas para promover as novas especificações como é o caso do HTML5  e do CSS3 (o próprio pessoal da W3 incentiva isso. Estampar em camisas, broches, adesivos, etc), outros usam indevidamente para mostrar que aderem aos novos padrões das especificações, outros, maioria dos que usam, realmente são *compliants* com a nova tecnologia.

Com o advento do HTML5, o desenvolvimento passou a se preocupar muito com a acessibilidade, dando ênfase, por exmeplo, na semântica do HTML, voltando as tecnologias para o usuário, assim os desenvolvedores podem moldar experiências melhores para eles.

Os selos não têm a ver com a velocidade de tráfego no seu site ou aplicação, mas sim com a **acessibilidade**.

A Internet é o espaço mais democrático que você jamais vai encontrar, no entanto, os desenvolvedores ainda pecam muito com relação ao acesso **universal**.

Você não devde se preocupar apenas com "está rodando", mas também com o "está rodando para todo mundo".

Como um leitor de telas vai se comportar ao entrar ler seu site?

É difícil seguir estritamente as regras do HTML5 e as novas tecnologias Web que o acompanham, e que revolucionam a Web a cada dia usando um *framework*, que é essencialmente genérico, na imensa maioria dos caso.

Veja o site de [**The Paciello Group**](https://www.paciellogroup.com/), sobre acessibilidade.

[Accessible Culture](http://accessibleculture.org/articles/2011/04/html5-aria-2011/)

Leia mais sobre o uso dos selos na [home page do logo do HTML5](https://www.w3.org/html/logo/).

Aprenda a usar uma ferramenta do tipo [HTML5 Outliner](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html5-outliner/afoibpobokebhgfnknfndkgemglggomo?hl=en).

Você pode usar quantos selos quiser, mas nós usuários vamos nos preocupar somente com um que diz "**site seguro**".

O usuário comum não se interessa por como os sites foram feitos, raramente vão ligar a tecnologia usada à segurança ou velocidade.

Procure mais sobre [Philippe Le Hégaret](https://www.w3.org/People/functions/project#plehegar).

espero ter contribuído para a discussão.

Comment: Olá! Vi que removeu a pergunta lá sobre JavaScript. Foi apenas uma opinião minha, talvez outros não achem o mesmo. Não quer restaurar a pergunta? Façamos o seguinte, eu restauro a pergunta e removo o meu comentário e vc remove o seu lá para não ficar sem nexo, aí aguarde algum tempinho para ver o que outros vão dizer. Que acha?

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76815/duvidas-sobre-front-end-javascript-css-e-html